# Way to kill python thread from inside thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some python code that currently performs expensive computation by performing the computation in parallel through many threads. For a given time period, many threads are created and started on the fly that share the same code which is explicitly stated within the run method of the thread. My question is how do I stop/kill a thread at the end of its run method? (the run is only called once) I need to do this in order to create more threads for the next batch of computation.

```
#Example

class someThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        #some init code
    def run(self):

        #Explicitly Stated Code without constant loops

        #Something performed to stop/kill this thread
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: Just return from the `run` method?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg That would effectively stop the thread from being active within the code, but it wouldn't stop the thread from existing. Which is important because I want to generate threads on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to signal the main thread that the worker thread is done, and then call [`join`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) on the thread.

Comment: how do i signal the main thread that the worker thread is done?

Comment: @tilaprimera The simplest way is simply a boolean flag, that the thread sets as the last thing it does before returning.